# How to call Spring Boot (using tomcat) url redirect no template engine like localhost:8080/sample/someparameter

Tags: spring-boot

I am using spring boot+restful WS+ angular2. Mow my url is like http://localhost:8080/accountSummary/someparameter

When I run this I am getting error below in the browser

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Thu Jun 30 16:24:03 EDT 2016
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Circular view path [index.html]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/accountSummary/index.html] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)
```

I have used below configurations in spring boot conf file under app folder:

```
@Controller
@Configuration
public class WebController extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

// first option I have tried

    /*public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/accountSummary/**").setViewName("index.html");
    }*/
```

// second option I have tried

```
   /* @RequestMapping(value = "/{[accountSummary:[^\\.]*}")
    public String redirect() {
        return "forward:/index.html";
    }*/
```

Third option I have tried

```
    @RequestMapping(value={"/accountSummary/{*}"},  produces="text/html")
    public String getIndex(Model model, HttpServletRequest request){
      return "index.html";
    }
}
```

Presently this is show stopper to me. I am using pure spring boot structure like I am moving all the web application content into static folder under target folder.

Answer (score 0):

You have been on the right path but used the wrong prefix. If you want to send a redirect you should use `redirect:` as a prefix instead of `forward:`.

Answer (score 0):

It got fixed using Angular2. I have kept {provide:LocationStrategy,useClass:HashLocationStrategy}. if you give localhost:8080/#/  -- it will redirect to pagename with parameter if you provide.

Thanks to all for helping me.

Answer (score -1):

```
@RestController
```

Add this annotation in your controller

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/accountSummary/someparameter", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

Add this on your **method level** and **change** according to *yours method*.

Comment: This will not send the redirect but just do a mapping. Returning String is perfectly ok but you'll have to send the right prefix.